# Access the Telerik RadScheduler's advanced edit form from another aspx page

Tags: asp.net, telerik, appointment, radscheduler

I want Access the Telerik RadScheduler's advanced edit form from another aspx page.

Is there any option to call the Advance Edit form with out the Telerik RadScheduler.

Answer (score 0):

I have found another way rather than accessing the advanced form template, I will create my own form and additionally I will add the "RadSchedulerRecurrenceEditor". So my form will be looking similar to the advanced form and I can generate the recurrence rule also.

Hope that it will solve my case.

Thank you all :)